# How to get the balance of impersonate account in hardhat

Tags: solidity, hardhat

I am new at hardhat, i saw how to impersonate account as it went successful i try to get the balance of that address, unable to get not sure why.
here is the output ...

i saw the some where like if it was not an impersonate account, and if we call getBalance it gets the hex and then we can use that ethers.utils.formatEther(HEX) to convert it into ether but i am getting diffrent out but why !!!!!

```
  Splitter
0xDA9dfA130Df4dE4673b89022EE50ff26f6EA73Cf
BigNumber { _hex: '0x01bf73960878776acb8e00', _isBigNumber: true }
    ✔ Impersonate Account (9313ms)


  1 passing (9s)
```

here is the code ...

```
describe("Splitter", function () {

it("Impersonate Account", async function (){
  const address_to_get = '0xDA9dfA130Df4dE4673b89022EE50ff26f6EA73Cf';
    await network.provider.request({
      method: "hardhat_impersonateAccount",
      params : [address_to_get],
    });

    const signer = await ethers.provider.getSigner(address_to_get);
    signer.address = signer._address;
    console.log(signer.address);

    balanceOfSigner = await ethers.provider.getBalance(address_to_get);

    console.log(balanceOfSigner);
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This piece of code `await signer.getBalance()` will return the balance in Wei. If you want to access the balance in ETH then use `ethers.utils.formatEther(await signer.getBalance())`.

Answer (score 0):

Ethers.js gives all number outputs as BigNumber. This is because many numbers used in contract simply wouldn't fit in the regular `number` type used in native JavaScript.

To print something human-friendly, you can just add `.toString()`. Or if you want to do, for example, some mathematics on the numbers, the BigNumber library has its own functionality: https://docs.ethers.io/v5/api/utils/bignumber/

Comment: but my out of 
`balanceOfSigner = await ethers.provider.getBalance(address_to_get);`
is
`BigNumber { _hex: '0x01bf73960878776acb8e00', _isBigNumber: true }`
instead of bignumber.

Comment: so i have to use `balanceOfSigner._hex` to get the hex of balance an then use `ethers.utils.formatEther(balanceOfSigner._hex);` to get value in numbers. so why i have to do so.

Comment: No. As the example (https://docs.ethers.io/v5/api/utils/display-logic/#utils-formatEther) shows, you can give it directly the BigNumber as input. You should never access the BigNumber's internal constructs (such as `_hex`), but use its native functions instead (of use the object directly, as in this case)